# Why does Tokio's Runtime::block_on_all require a future with a 'static lifetime?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

When dealing with Tokio and futures, the futures passed to the Tokio runtime must have a `'static` lifetime most of the time. I understand that because the future might be moved to another thread where it can potentially outlive the place it was defined.

There is a method [`Runtime::block_on_all`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.1.8/tokio/runtime/struct.Runtime.html#method.block_on_all) which guarantees that the future called will be terminated by the end of the call, it even returns the result of running this future.

In that case, I don't get (except for simplicity of the Tokio code) why the future must be `'static`.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 3):

Looking a little further, it seems I'm right and they have an issue about it: [#431 Drop `'static` bound on `Runtime::block_on[_all]`](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/issues/431)

Comment: It would not be the first Rust API to start conservative, and loosen the requirements over time, so I don't think it's necessary so much as it was *obviously* correct and therefore helped get the release out of the door.